# iOS7 when UIsearchbar added in UINavigationBar not showing cancel button

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios7, uisearchbar

I add UISearchBar above UINavigationBar and set UIsearchbar showsCancelButton YES, work fine in iOS6 but in iOS7 not showing cancel button.
 I used below code snippet

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 44)];
searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
searchBar.translucent = NO;
[searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar   addSubview:searchBar];
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For some reason iOS7 does not show the cancel button when added to a navigation bar. This also happens if you try setting it as the titleView of a navigationItem.

You can circumvent this problem by wrapping the UISearchBar in another UIView first. Here's how I do it as a titleView:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
[searchBar sizeToFit];
UIView *barWrapper = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:searchBar.bounds];
[barWrapper addSubview:searchBar];
self.navigationItem.titleView = barWrapper;
```

Comment: I've encountered the same problem and tried your solution. However, the search bar picks up a different style and the size isn't correct. Have you further developed this solution and fixed the details?

Comment: Wrapping the UISearchBar in a UIView before placing in the UINavigationBar worked for me. I am, however, adding it as a subview instead of the titleView.

Comment: It's true the style of the bar changes and doesn't fit too well with the nav.bar. I did searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal which suits my needs at least.

Comment: For me, it seems to work except that i cant see the search bar at all. If i click in that area the keyboard and search results come up fine, but i cant see any of what im typing..

Comment: If your app enables both portrait and landscape mode, then it won't recalculate the size properly when you switch orientations. This is where auto-layout would be helpful, but it would involve some finagling with the titleView property, which auto adjusts size when an item is set. 

So annoying. 

I ended up just creating my own cancel button and placing it as the rightBarButtonItem.

Comment: the accepted answer is a good start, but as people say, it messes up the style and look. @Rodskjegg style line plus wrapping the search bar in a uiview thats added as a subview to nav bar worked for me

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem, on iPhone search bar with cancel button show well, but on iPad the cancel button wasn't shown.  Wrapping the UIsearchBar to UIView like @Rodskjegg throw style issue. On iPad UIsearchBar setting it as the titleView of a navigationItem and add UIBarButtonItem to setRighttBarButtonItem as UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel.

```
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:Nil animated:YES];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar;

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(searchBarCancelButtonClicked:)];

        [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem: cancelButton animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem: nil animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: I also had some style issues (searchbar was to big initially and did not resize correctly on interface rotation) and solved by adding a bar button myself .. not the cleanest approach but anyway. Thanks for the answer

Comment: This is the least hacky solution IMO. It worked better for me than the `addSubview` method above without any jarring frame/ animation issues. Great solution!

Answer (score 4):

Since iOS 7 you can just set the property `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` to `YES` on the  `UISearchDisplayController` to automatically get a `UISearchbar` in the NavigationBar.

Comment: And if one is not using a search display controller?

Comment: Exactly. I just want to put my search bar inside the navigation item.

Comment: Not seeing an iOS8 deprecation at all.

Comment: UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 8 ... You should use UISearchController now.

Comment: ...if you do not need to both support iOS 7 and 8

Answer (score 4):

Yes
In iOS 7 button is located on the screen, but it's title could be invisible
My solution was to set Search Style to "Minimal" and choose bar tint colour for "Cancel" text colour in IB

[image]

And the Result in a simulator :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, here's my solution, hope this helps.

Some further explanation:
I found out that sending `setShowsCancelButton:animated:` to the searchBar, it just works like magic. And the cleanest way to add a searchBar to navigation bar is `self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar;` The appropriate timing for calling `setShowsCancelButton:animated:` is in `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:` and `searchBarTextDidEndEditing:` delegate methods, so remember to set `self` to be the delegate of searchBar.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES]; 
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are typically frowned upon on SO. You should try adding some explanation as to *why/how* your code works.

Comment: Answer edited to give more explanation, I thought the code itself is pretty self-explanatory, don't be harsh on me, thanks.

Comment: I wasn't harsh on you. As your first answer on SO, I simply commented that an explanation makes for a much better answer. It may seem self explanatory to you and many others but it may not be for someone else with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, on iPhone the search cancel was shown well, but on iPad it didn't.

The workaround of wrapping the UISearchBar in another UIView didn't work well for me since it had different appearance and wrong width on rotation.

My solution is a simple one - use search WITHOUT cancel, and add cancel as UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the search bar delegate and use this:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
}
```