# UISearchBar not fitting in UINavigationBar on iPad - iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uisearchbar, titleview, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to place a UISearchBar in a UINavigationBar's titleView.

I have two solutions, both are inconvenient.

First is :

```
[self setSearchController:[[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController]];
[self.searchController setSearchResultsUpdater:searchResultsController];
[self.searchController setHidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation:NO];
[self.searchController.searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
[self.searchController setDelegate:self];
[self.searchController setDimsBackgroundDuringPresentation:NO];
[self.searchController.searchBar setDelegate:self];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:self.searchController.searchBar];
[self setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];
[self.searchController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES];
```

When not searching, the result looks okay.

[image: Not searching mode]

But when search starts, the titleView extends too much on the right. Indeed, cancel button is visible, but just not on screen...

[image]

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19053199/3179378) I tried to wrap the UISearchBar in a another UIView before adding it to the navigationItem.

```
[self setSearchController:[[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController]];
[self.searchController setSearchResultsUpdater:searchResultsController];
[self.searchController setHidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation:NO];
[self.searchController.searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
[self.searchController setDelegate:self];
[self.searchController setDimsBackgroundDuringPresentation:NO];
[self.searchController.searchBar setDelegate:self];

[self.searchController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO];
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
UIView *titleViewWrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.searchController.searchBar.frame];
[titleViewWrapper addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:titleViewWrapper];

[self setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];
[self.searchController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES];
```

And the result it the following:

Not searching:

[image]

Searching:

[image]

I am managing left/right bar button item showing/hiding myself in UISearchController's delegate methods.

This occurs in the Simulator, only on iPad.

Any ideas?