# UISearchbar cancel button is not displaying in ipad layout

Tags: uisearchbar

I'm working in `xcode` version 6.1. I've just drag and drop the `UISearchBar` in my `UIViewController`...Now i just copied and paste this `storyboard` for iPad device..But for the iPhone device i can see the cancel button,,but for the Ipad device the cancel button didn't appear..

**Below is the code**

```
 [searchBar setPlaceholder:AMLocalizedString(@"Search people", nil)];
 id barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil];
 [barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar setTitle:AMLocalizedString(@"Cancel",nil)];
```

Can anyone help me!!!!!

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Maximilian http://stackoverflow.com/a/33591636/1023074

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a rightBarButtonItem instead

Answer (score -2):

I understand that you are trying to embed the UISearchBar in the NavigationBar/Toolbar; if so, here is a solution to do that programmatically:
[iOS7 when UIsearchbar added in UINavigationBar not showing cancel button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986407/ios7-when-uisearchbar-added-in-uinavigationbar-not-showing-cancel-button)

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
[searchBar sizeToFit];
UIView *barWrapper = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:searchBar.bounds];
[barWrapper addSubview:searchBar];
self.navigationItem.titleView = barWrapper;
```