# Cancel button is not shown in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have `UICollectionView`. On clicking search button in `UINavigationBar`, I am adding the `UISearchController`'s `searchbar` as titleview for `UINavigationItem`. For iPhone it is working properly. For iPad the `cancel` button is not shown. The Searchbar alone takes the entire width.

[image]

Can anyone help me out on this?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using different storyboards or xib for iPhone and iPad?

Comment: No. I am not using storyboards or xib.

Comment: Try to set `searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS7 when UIsearchbar added in UINavigationBar not showing cancel button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986407/ios7-when-uisearchbar-added-in-uinavigationbar-not-showing-cancel-button)

Comment: The documentation clearly states: "The value of this property is ignored, and no cancel button is displayed, for apps running on iPad". I don't think this is appropriate, especially for slide over / split view scenarios. So I filed a radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/37498710

Answer (score 18, accepted):

iOS7 does not show the cancel button when added to a navigation bar.You can put searchbar in another view like this.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
[searchBar sizeToFit];
UIView *viewForSearchBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:searchBar.bounds];
[viewForSearchBar addSubview:searchBar];
self.navigationItem.titleView = viewForSearchBar;
```

Comment: Good pick from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986407/ios7-when-uisearchbar-added-in-uinavigationbar-not-showing-cancel-button

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, on iPhone the search cancel was shown well, but on iPad it didn't.

The workaround of wrapping the `UISearchBar` in another `UIView` didn't work well for me since it had different appearance and wrong width on rotation.

My solution is a simple one - use search WITHOUT cancel, and add cancel as a `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: This seems like the correct answer to me. The cancel button isn't supported on iPad, so just add it manually as a `UIBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Added rightBarButtonItem with selector will work fine for me. And adding searchBar inside view before setting to navigation title view was not showing properly.
Code:- 
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissView))
func dismissView() {
        if self.controller?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) == nil {
            self.controller?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

As per apple documentation [setShowsCancelButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar/1624293-setshowscancelbutton?language=objc)

> Cancel buttons are not displayed for apps running on iPad, even when
>   you specify YES for the showsCancelButton parameter.

I am not sure about the alternate but this is what apple provides us.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Add a checkmark for shows cancel button.

[image]

Comment: the OP mentioned that it works in iPhone but not iPad

Answer (score 1):

Swift version :-

I tried the @Nikita Khandelwal method, but still it doesn't fit for ipad view. Here is the swift code, which was given as corrected answer :-

```
let searchBar: UISearchBar = UISearchBar()
searchBar.showCancelButton = true
searchBar.placeholder = "Search Your Job Title"
searchBar.fitToSize()
searchBar.delegate = self //do not need if you delegate searchBar
let viewForSearchBar: UIView = UIView(frame: searchBar.bounds)
viewForSearchBar.addSubview(searchBar)
self.navigationItem.titleView = viewForSearchBar
```

********* But There is another way to set cancel button correctly and fit for the view :-

1. Set search bar as the Navigation bar title view :-

   ```
   let searchBar: UISearchBar = UISearchBar()
   searchBar.showCancelButton = true
   searchBar.placeholder = "Search Your Job Title"
   searchBar.delegate = self //do not need if you delegate searchBar
   self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
   ```
2. Drag and drop Bar button to the right side of the view controller & name it as Cancel.
3. Then connect that button to this function :-

   ```
   @IBAction func iPadCancelButton(sender: AnyObject) {
          UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("resignFirstResponder", to:nil, from:nil, forEvent:nil)
         self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 13 built with Xcode 11, I'm needing to set manually set the display value on the cancel button, depending on whether the search controller is visible