# Searchbar's cancel button not visible on iPads

Tags: swift, ipad, uisearchbar

First I want to say that I didn't find any good answer about the topic, so I ask the following question.

I created `searchbar` using storyboard. The problem is that on the search button click, it shows the searchbar and on cancel it hides the `searchbar`, and it is working properly on iPhones. But for some weird reason the cancel button is not visible on **iPad**s. What can cause this?

This is how I create the `searchbar`:

```
//Create searchbar
    func createSearchBar(){
        
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.184, green:0.996, blue:0.855, alpha:1.00)
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search brands"
        searchBar.delegate = self
        
       
        
        searchBar.hidden =  false
        searchBar.alpha = 0
        
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
        navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(menuButton, animated: true)
        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(searchButtton, animated: true)
        
        
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.searchBar.alpha = 1
            }, completion: { finished in
                self.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        })
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Faced the same one of my project. I've posted on apple forum and lot of developers commented as a xcode bug. So I added the cancel button manually for ipad views

```
 func configureCancelBarButton() {
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem()
    cancelButton.image = UIImage(named: "cancelButton")
    cancelButton.action = #selector(viewController.ipadCancelButton(_:))
    cancelButton.target = self
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(cancelButton, animated: true)
}
```

And I previously posted an answer about this question. [Check that too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474494/cancel-button-is-not-shown-in-uisearchbar). :)

Answer (score 7):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar/1624283-showscancelbutton

The value of this property is ignored, and no cancel button is displayed, for apps running on iPad.

Apple add that in documents!

Comment: What's the reason for not having the cancel button on iPad?

Answer (score 2):

**UISearchBar works differently on iPads and iPhones when used as a navigationItem. On an iPad, the cancel button is replaced by a "back" button, while on an iPhone, the cancel button is still displayed as a button.***

1. On an iPad, if you are using a UISearchBar as a navigationItem in a UINavigationBar, the cancel button will not be displayed. However, if you are using a UISearchBar in any other context, such as within a view controller, the cancel button will be displayed and will function as expected.
2. On an iPhone, the UISearchBar can be used both as a navigationItem and within a view controller. In both cases, the cancel button will be displayed and will function as expected.
3. When the UISearchBar is used as a navigationItem on an iPhone, the cancel button is displayed as a right bar button item when the user starts editing the search bar. This allows the user to easily cancel the search and return to the previous screen.

   > On an iPad, if you are using a UISearchBar as a navigationItem in a UINavigationBar, the cancel button will not be displayed. However, if you are using a UISearchBar in any other context, such as within a view controller, the cancel button will be displayed and will function as expected.

   ```
    func setupCancelButton() {
   let cancelButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    // Set button title
   cancelButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
    // Add target
   cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
   cancelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   let image = UIImage(named: "cancel_icon")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
   // Set image 
   cancelButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
   cancelButton.tintColor = .black

   searchBar.addSubview(cancelButton)
   searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)

   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       cancelButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBar.topAnchor, constant: 0),
       cancelButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
       cancelButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBar.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
       cancelButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
   ])}

   @objc func cancelButtonTapped() {
   searchBar.text = ""
   searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
   ```

   }

> Call the above function from viewDidLoad to setup the UISearchBar

Answer (score 0):

The UISearchbar's cancel button will work in iPads if you are NOT using the UISearchbar as NavigationBarItem.