# iOS 11 SearchBar in NavigationBar

Tags: uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, ios11

With iOS 11 Apple has redesigned the UISearchBar by making the corners rounder and the height bigger. Adding a UISearchBar to the navigationBar is pretty simple by just setting it as the titleView of the navigationItem using `navigationItem.titleView = searchBar`.

However, in iOS 11 it does not seem to work anymore as expected.
Have a look at the screens where we compare the same setup using iOS 10 and iOS 11

**iOS 10**
[image]

**iOS 11**
[image]

You can clearly see that the SearchBar increases the size of the NavigationBar but the bar buttons do not get aligned correctly. Also the searchBar does not use the available space on the left anymore.

Putting the searchBar into a wrapper view to get the cancel button on iPad as described here [Cancel button is not shown in UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474494/cancel-button-is-not-shown-in-uisearchbar) also does not seem work anymore since the searchBar is then not visible at all.

If anyone has similar issues or already knowns how to fix/improve this I would be very thankful.

This was built using Xcode 9 Beta 4. Maybe future releases will fix this issue.

**UPDATE:**

Since this does not get fixed we decided to use following solution.
We added a new UIBarButtonItem to the NavBar which then presents a new ViewController where we only put a searchBar and nothing else into the NavBar which seems to work. Using the selected answer may be the best solution since Apple with iOS 11 wants us to use this new design even if it does not give us the result we originally wanted. Another way to possible solve this could be a custom SearchBar but this is another topic.

Comment: I've spent some couple of hours trying to solve the same kind of issue. Kindly please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53264329/3231194 :) I posted this as an answer, so that it could be seen easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 52):

There's a new searchController property on navigationItem in iOS 11.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897305-searchcontroller

Use like this...

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     navigationItem.searchController = searchController
} else {
     // Fallback on earlier versions
     navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar
}
```

In Objective-C the if statement looks like this:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
```

On iOS 11, if you don't set `navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false`, the search bar may initially be hidden, unless the user scrolls down to reveal it. If you do set it to false, it appears stacked below where the title would go without the user having to scroll.

Comment: My answer is similar to @cook answer, but I thought the link and the code might help clarify a bit.

Comment: This will not give the results as original described.  Using the searchController property will put the search bar below the navigation.

Comment: This works on iPhone but doesn't work on iPad for me.

Comment: Do you know the navigationbar height in this case? Will it change?

Answer (score 16):

You can change the height of UISearchBar in iOS 11 by adding a constraint of height 44:

```swift
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: This makes top and bottom bezel shorter. I tried this objective-c solution: [[self.notesSearchBar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44.0] setActive:YES], but I dont like this solution because it makes top bottom margin thinner and weird.

Comment: This worked for me. It repositions my search bar maintaining the correct layout.

Comment: This is the correct solution however, especially if you are targeting both iOS 10 and iOS 11 with your app

Comment: This solves the height issue, but does not address the width problem as posted by the author.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue and after a few day googling the issue, I found this page - https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://www.jianshu.com/p/262f6e34a7d3&prev=search.

This page leads to this git repo - https://github.com/DreamTravelingLight/searchBarDemo - this demo project shows how to use the old way with titleView to still have a searchBar without the sizing issue.

The key lines are these

```
_searchBar = [self addSearchBarWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kScreenWidth - 2 * 44 - 2 * 15, 44)];
UIView *wrapView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_searchBar.frame];
[wrapView addSubview:_searchBar];
self.navigationItem.titleView = wrapView;
```

If you embed the UISearchBar inside a view, and set that wrapView as the titleView, the UISearchBar will have the size you set for it, and will fit the nav bar as intended.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Why  kScreenWidth - 2 * 44 - 2 * 15?

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use the native `UISearchBar` *(and avoid the needs of creating your custom components)* in the iOS 11+ `navigationBar`, you could create a container view for that `searchBar` to have full control over the frame. This container view would be the superview of the `searchBar` you pass in.

**Something like:**

```
class SearchBarContainerView: UIView {

    let searchBar: UISearchBar

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        searchBar = UISearchBar()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar = searchBar
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 0.0, height: 44.0))
        addSubview(searchBar)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        searchBar.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

**And then:**

```
let containerView = SearchBarContainerView(searchBar: searchController.searchBar)
containerView.frame.size.width = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width ?? 0.0
navigationItem.titleView = containerView
```

> **Note** that this is just a quick demo and is not ready for `navigationBar` frame changes (display rotation etc.). You could solve that with e.g. `autoresizingMask`.

Comment: This works! Also update containerView.frame in ```override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) { coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { // here }... } ``` is enough.

Answer (score 3):

**Make a summary in iOS 14+**

First to fix push cause extra height:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout() // force update layout
    navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded() // to fix height of the navigation bar
}
```

Second to fix pop to origin height:

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

All above code set in the controller with search bar.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to deal with setting the new UINavigationItem.searchController property to your UISearchController object. That's how you get the new effect as seen in Messages. It looks like the old behavior is just plain gone. I hope I'm wrong, but the whole API got an overhaul for 11. I know it's buggy in general so we'll see with newer betas and the GM if this gets fixed. (Writing at time of Beta 6)

Answer (score 1):

This helped me:

```
    if ([self.navigationItem respondsToSelector:@selector(setSearchController:)])
    {
        [self.navigationItem performSelector:@selector(setSearchController:) withObject:self.searchController];
    }
    else
    {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out with `searchController` and`searchBar` but found that`searchBar` is meeting my requirements(search on click of the search button).

```
-(void)searchBarSetUp{
//Search button to reload the radio content.
self.searchButton.action = @selector(addSearchBarToNavigationTitleView);
self.searchButton.target = self;

//search bar initialization
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
searchBar.delegate = self;
searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
[searchBar sizeToFit]; }

-(void)addSearchBarToNavigationTitleView {
// Install the search bar as the table header.
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;}
```

**I too faced difficulties to handle the black screen if I am using `searchControl`.**