# IOS keyboard for textview at bottom and searchbar at top

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have an textview at bottom of screen and search bar at top of screen. Following is my code to solve the problem of keyboard when textview is pressed

```
extension UIView { 
    func bindToKeyboard(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(UIView.keyboardWillChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        let duration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
        let curve = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
        let curFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let targetFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let deltaY = targetFrame.origin.y - curFrame.origin.y

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
            self.frame.origin.y += deltaY

        },completion: {(true) in
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```

But when I press search bar then the screen moves up and search bar disappears. If I do `view.bindToKeyboard()` then the edittext is proper after displaying the keyboard.

One solution which I tried was binding the outlet of textview to keyboard but the textview disappears as soon as I start typing.

Comment: What are you using UISearchBar or UISearchBarController? put your configuration for search bar.

Comment: You should try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45826168/2553730

Comment: @guru I am using UISearchBar

Comment: could you please share screenshots or small video, so we can see the actual behaviour.

Comment: @guru will upload soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to know when the keyboard is going to appear. Searchbar has a textfield. So when it's tapped it opens the keyboard like your textview and the *keyboardWillChange* is called.

```
   keyboardWillChange(_ notification: NSNotification)
```

So the keyboard appears and hides your searchbar. You can detect searchbar tap and cancel the notification there.

```
    func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool
    {
       //Dismiss your keyboard notification here

       return true
    }
```

You should use a library to handle this situation. I'm suggesting **IQKeyboardManager**. [IQKeyBoardManager Github.](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

Answer (score 0):

I edit my earlier respond... have you try to put your searchBar into navigationBar?

something like this (just put on viewDidLoad):

```
navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying Cannot assign to property: 'inputView' is a get-only property

Comment: I'm sorry.. my mistake. Have you try to put your searchBar to navigationBar?

Comment: The  navigation bar also disappears when pressing on the edit field at the bottom