# 'cancel' button of searchbar disappear in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

My app needs support universal devices.

And in that, there is a view controller which have UISearchController. It can show normally in iPhone device, but in iPad, the 'cancel' button disappear.

[iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/519FN.png)

[iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW53Y.png)

It is the relevant code about searchbar in the view controller, following.

```
func configureSearchController() {
    self.collectionView!.updateConstraints()
    resultsTableController = SearchBookResultTableViewController()
    resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "书籍、作者、出版社"
    // stress
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

I want to know the reason of the problem, and in which way I can solve it.

Seek help! Thx.

Comment: This is a guess - try moving the .showsCancelButton before the .sizeToFit()

Comment: @MikeTaverne I try your way, and the problem still exits. The `showsCancelButton` property is `true`, which is default. I only want to stress the property is true, so I write it.  *>.<*

Comment: Given that there is the "keyboard dismiss" button on the iPad keyboard, the cancel button isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the same situation in iOS 7 in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986407/ios7-when-uisearchbar-added-in-uinavigationbar-not-showing-cancel-button). And I use the same way to solve my problem. But I don't know why the way, create a new `UIView`, can solve it? What's the different between them?

```
self.collectionView!.updateConstraints()
resultsTableController = SearchBookResultTableViewController()
resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableController)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "书籍、作者、出版社"

let SearchView: UIView = UIView(frame: searchController.searchBar.bounds)
SearchView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)

navigationItem.titleView = SearchView
```